# ¿Cómo poner un icono en un jframe de java maven en netbeans?

Tags: java, maven

Me encuentro aprendiendo sobre la creación de proyectos en java con maven en el ide Netbeans y me surgió la necesidad de cambiar el ícono de la ventana.

En el java con ant (creación sencilla del proyecto) si puedo realizar el cambio de ícono de la siguiente manera:

```
public Interfaz() {
     String pathImage = "/icono/icono.png";
     initComponents();
     this.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(pathImage)).getImage();
}
```

En el proyecto con maven el path sería distinto por lo que hay más carpetas desde la subcarpeta src, es decir, /src/main/java/com/prueba/imagen/imagen.png

La cadena anterior la pongo adentro de `getResource()` obviamente con comillas dobles y me sale un error en dicha línea, también intente poniendo `\\src\\main...` y de igual manera se muestra un error diciendo: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null` .

Cómo se puede prevenir esto, o qué estaría mal en el código

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se crea un proyecto en Maven, este gestor de dependencias separa las imágenes en la carpeta resources de tu aplicación. Dicha carpeta se debe encontrar en src/main/java. Una vez creada, crea una nueva carpeta llamada iconos, y ahí coloca todos tus iconos. Entonces, quedaría algo así tu directorio:

```
src
|___main
    |___java
    |___resources
        |___iconos
           |___icono.png
```

Ahora, tu código modificado sería el siguiente :

```
public Interfaz() {
 String pathImage = "/iconos/icono.png";
 initComponents();
 this.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(pathImage).getImage());
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta; ya agregué estas líneas y al correr el proyecto lamentablemente me sigue mostrando el icono de la taza, tal vez se debe hacer algo más?

Comment: Puedes hablarme por discord para que me mandes capturas del error: j0rgitopro